# Sending SMS from django app

Tags: python, django, sms

I came to the requirement to send SMS from my django app. Its a dashboard from multiple clients, and each client will have the ability to send programable SMS.

Is this achievable with django smsish? I have found some packages that aren't updated, and I sending email sms is not possible.

All answers found are old and I have tried all approaches suggested.
Do I have to use services like twilio mandatorily? Thanks

Comment: twillio isn't mandatory but it will save you tons of time to start from scratch, and it's kind of proven by the usage from whatsapp or alike. you can of course start from scratch and build your own via SMPP protocol, it's your call.

Comment: You can use services like https://www.smsapi.com/. They have nice API: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smsapi-client/1.1.3

Comment: I have had a look at services like those, but are quite expensive, considering the ammount of sms I will be sending. The same applies to twilio.

Answer (score 1):

Using Twilio is not mandatory, but I do recommend it. Twilio does the heavy lifting, your Django App just needs to make the proper API Requests to Twilio, which has great documentation on it.

Twilio has Webhooks as well which you can 'hook' to specific Django Views and process certain events. As for the 'programmable' aspect of your app you can use django-celery, django-cron, RabbitMQ or other task-queueing software.